# Prove the following complex integral satisfies $\mid \int_\ell \frac{z^3}{z^2+1}dz \mid \leq \frac{9\pi}{8}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Prove $\mid \int_\ell \frac{z^3}{z^2+1}dz \mid \leq \frac{9\pi}{8}$ where $\ell$ is $|z|=3,\Re(z)\geq 0$.

My attempt:
$$\mid \int_\ell \frac{z^3}{z^2+1}dz \mid \leq  \int_\ell  \frac{\mid z\mid^3}{\mid z^2+1\mid} \ dz $$ and therefore, since $|z|=3\Rightarrow |z|^3=27, |z^2+1|\geq |z|^2-1=8$, we obtain
$$
\mid \int_\ell \frac{z^3}{z^2+1}dz \mid \leq \frac{27}{8}\cdot 3\pi,
$$
where $3\pi $ is the curve perimeter.
The same minimal value for the denominator is obtained when taking $z=x+iy$ and examining the value of $|z^2+1|^2 = 4\cdot (25-y^2)$ (where $x=\sqrt{9-y^2}$).

Unfortunately, I cannot see how I can refine this argument to obtain the required bound. Will be happy to receive some help with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to reduce the power by polynomial division, so $\frac{z^3}{z^2+1}=z-\frac{z}{z^2+1}$

Then $$|\int_\ell \frac{z^3}{z^2+1}dz|= |-\int_\ell \frac{z}{z^2+1}dz +\int_\ell z dz| $$

By direct computation or Cauchy (moving to the vertical segment from $-3$ to $3$) we have $\int_\ell z dz=0$, so now your reasoning gives the required bound $9\pi/8$